# How to check filtered checkboxs only in AngularJS in select all checboxes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this angular table:

```
$scope.customers = [{
  first_name: "Oded",
  last_name: "Taizi",
  id: 1,
  type_link: 2
}, {
  first_name: "Ploni",
  last_name: "Almoni",
  id: 2,
  type_link: 2
}, {
  first_name: "Fred",
  last_name: "Dyllan",
  id: 3,
  type_link: 2
}, {
  first_name: "Dan",
  last_name: "Omer",
  id: 4,
  type_link: 4
}, {
  first_name: "Amir",
  last_name: "Maly",
  id: 5,
  type_link: 3
}, {
  first_name: "Noa",
  last_name: "Levy",
  id: 6,
  type_link: 3
}];
```

And this function:

```
 $scope.checkAll = function(isCheck) {
    angular.forEach($scope.customers, function(cust) {
      cust.select = isCheck.selectAll;
    });
 };
```

And I want to filter this data by free search and by group. This is working for me.
My problem is when clicking the select all checkbox, it selects all the checkboxes even when filtered

I only want to check all the filtered rows.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odedtaizi/oykpm95n/13/).
Try to filter by the select box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a reference to your filtered array:

```
<tr ng-repeat="cust in filteredCustomers = (customers | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort | 
    filter :searchInput | filter: {type_link: typesModel}) ">
```

which would be accessible directly as `$scope.filteredCustomers`.

Now, instead of all the customers, check only the ones from `$scope.filteredCustomers`. Like:

```
$scope.checkAll = function(isCheck) {
  angular.forEach($scope.filteredCustomers, function(cust) {
    cust.select = isCheck.selectAll;
  });
};
```

[**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3hyex7y9/) | [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ad8u1pq/) with `$scope.filteredCustomers`

Comment: fyi You don't need to pass it to the function as it should be created on the scope so you can just change it to use `$scope.filteredCustomers`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But the `filteredCustomers` doesn't work as `$scope.filteredCustomers`

Comment: @oded it does, check this: http://jsfiddle.net/6ad8u1pq/ and http://jsfiddle.net/3hyex7y9/ for both different ways.. both work

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set the value when checking to $scope.selectAll`?

```
$scope.checkAll = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.customers, function(cust) {
      cust.select = $scope.selectAll;
    });
};
```

### [Forked your Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/fpv784s1/)

As a side note, you can also change the checkbox of each customer to something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="cust.select" ng-click="cust.select = !cust.select">
```

Comment: Because with his function you can unselect them all as well, also this doesn't actually answer his question at all.

Comment: @George My bad, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also replicate the logic using filters.

Inject the `$filter` service into your controller constructor like:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http,$filter){ ... });
```

Then you can use `$filter('<filter_name>')` in order to get the corresponding filter:

```
  $scope.checkAll = function(isCheck) {
        let customersBySearchInput = $filter('filter')($scope.customers, $scope.searchInput);
        let customersBySearchInputAndType = $filter('filter')(customersBySearchInput, {type_link: $scope.typesModel});

        angular.forEach(customersBySearchInputAndType, function(cust) {
          cust.select = isCheck.selectAll;
        });
     };
```

Having the same logic in multiple places would not be a good idea. Therefore you could create a function in your controller which does the filtering then that can be reused in your template and other functions.

**NOTE: don't forget about testability -** usually is better to reduce the amount of code complexity in your template and provide controller methods that does the business or that delegates the concern to another service. Regarding testability, this would improve as you can easily unit test your controller logic and increase your code coverage.